# После проведения документа в 1C нужно добавить данные в справочник

Tags: база-данных, 1с

У меня есть справочник "Абитуриенты" и справочник "Студенты", а также документ "Приказ о зачислении". Нужно, чтобы после внесения нужных абитуриентов в табличную часть документа и последующем его проведении, в справочник "Студенты" добавились эти самые абитуриенты. [image: На картинке то, как выглядит сам документ]

Comment: мне кажется что справочник должен быть "физичиские лица" один, а аббитуриенты и студенты должны быть регистрами

Answer (score 1):

Можно в событии "ПослеЗаписиНаСервере", которое располагается в модуле формы ([подробнее](https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/1175475/)) сделать процедуру, которая будет создавать новые элементы в справочнике.

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ПослеЗаписиНаСервере(ТекущийОбъект, ПараметрыЗаписи)
  
  //В цикле обходите вашу ТЧ из документа
  Для каждого Строка из Абитуриенты Цикл
    
    // Создаете новый экземпляр
    НовыйСтудент = Справочники.Студенты.СоздатьЭлемент();
   
    // Заполняете реквизиты
    // НовыйСтудент.ФИО = Строка.Абитуриент;
   
    // Записываете. Если возникает исключение - выдаете ошибку.
    Попытка
      НовыйСтудент.Записать();
    Исключение
      Сообщить(ОписаниеОшибки());
    КонецПопытки;

  КонецЦикла;

КонецПроцедуры
```

Comment: @DodShoT, хорошо что поправили :)
Ибо писал с телефона и по памяти.